# What URL for rest web service?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I was looking at different approaches to deploying a jax-rs web service on jboss and found two potential approaches (these can be seen below)

**approach 1**

```
@ApplicationPath("rest") 
public class ServerStart extends Application{

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public ServerStart() {
        singletons.add(new ExposedFunctions());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Swiped Service</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>swipedserver</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.swiped.main.ServerStart</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>swipedserver</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

class to take requests

```
@Path("/functions")
public class ExposedFunctions {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExposedFunctions.class);
    private DBFactoryController controller = new DBFactoryController();

    public ExposedFunctions(){
        if(controller!= null){
            controller.buildCache();
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/register/{username}/{password}/{email}/{firstname}/{lastname}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String register(@PathParam("username") String username, @PathParam("password") String password, @PathParam("email") String email, @PathParam("firstname") String firstname, @PathParam("lastname") String lastname) {
        System.out.println(true);
        if(StringUtilities.stringEmptyOrNull(username, password, email, firstname, lastname)){
            logger.error("String was null or empty when registering");
        }

        RegistrationStatus status = controller.register(username, password, email, firstname, lastname);
        return status.getValue();
    }
}
```

**approach 2**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create(BASE_URI);
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Press Enter to stop the server. ");
        System.in.read();
        server.stop(0);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now in approach two it is pretty explicit in how you call the service, the URL is predefined in a variable BASE_URI

In the first approach this is not provided - so how do we no how to call this service?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand... BASE_URI is in the second one, not the first. Also, the second is a main function that starts an application, the first is part of an application, and would require some other configuration presumably.

Comment: sorry for that - poorly worded from me, have edited the post

Comment: Right, but you still haven't provided enough in the first scenario to know. There should be, for example, a web.xml file mapping a JAX-RS servlet to a URL, a WAR file that gets deployed to jboss, that go into determining the URL.

Comment: added some more details towards approach one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about how to access the endpoint you've created, then you will need to deploy your java web project to some app server (e.g. Tomcat, WAS, etc.), and you can access it through any sort of client (e.g. a web browser).

You can deploy it to a server either by exporting the the project as  a war, and deploying the war to an app server, or by running it in eclipse, assuming you have the correct environment setup (wtp).

Comment: i have deployed it to a remote jboss instance running on the ip 94.5.19.27 - the thing is - i have no idea what url i need to call it on

Comment: from how you have it setup it appears to be: <host>:<port>/<contextRoot>/rest/functions/register/{username}/{password}/{email}/{firstname}/{lastname} where you have your parameters filled in, of course.

Comment: how would i determine the port

Comment: I don't know.  It's the port you specified when you started JBoss.  I think by default it's 8080.

Comment: ok and one last question :) context root?

Comment: If you created this in eclipse, usually it prompts you to set one, but for JBoss you can do this: https://community.jboss.org/thread/204687 or http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch06.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58831/discussion-between-zac-lozano-and-biscuit128).